# Angular 2.4.8 App_Initializer

Tags: angular

I use an APP_INITIALIZER loading data from server and a guard with CanActivate. I use Angular 2.4.8 and I see that CanActivate in my guard is called BEFORE APP_INITIALIZER finish calling the validate function...

Is it a correct behavior ?

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: ContextService) => () =>  config.validate(), deps: [ContextService], multi: true }
```

the function config.validate() returns a promise. Here the code

```
 validate() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
         this.http.get('/api/v1/check').map(res => res.json()),
         this.http.get('/api/v1/me').map(res => res.json())
     ).map(
        data => {

            console.log("data loaded");

            ... stuff ...

             return this.hasValidLicence;
         }).toPromise();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This issue has been fixed since https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14681. Please try angular 2.4.9. It should be working fine. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, answer to your question is both **yes** and **no**. Router in version 2.4.8 has been changed and now navigation starts also in **APP_INITIALIZER** loop, meaning potentially CanActivate is triggered before your ContextService factory finishes. Route (NavigationEnd) will not be resolved until all APP_INITIALIZER tasks finish but that might not be what you want.

If you want to make sure that data is there before you finish loading/navigating to a page you can do one of the following things:

- Downgrade to version 2.4.7 since they realized this is not solution people are happy with and commit has been reverted already
- Add ContextService dependency to your CanActivate so that route is not activated (and resolved) until your factory finishes loading the data
- Use quick fix explained at official repo https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14588